# Using CGRectIntersectsRect with IBOutletCollection of an array of uiviews

Tags: arrays, uiview, for-loop, cgrect, iboutletcollection

Hello I have 3 views as part of an IBOutletCollection. They are in the array called myArrayOfViews. I'd like to be able to use CGRectIntersectsRect to determine when any of these 3 views overlap but so far no luck. I thought I could loop through the array twice and then run CGRectIntersectsRect but no luck. What am I missing. Thanks in advance!

```
for (UIView *view1 in self.myArrayOfViews) {
    NSLog(@"view1 is %@",view1);
    for (UIView *view2 in self.myArrayOfViews) {
        NSLog(@"view2 is %@",view2);

        if( CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
            NSLog(@"overlap!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: it always thinks it overlaps. The loop runs, I need to specify better what I want to log b/c it's a lot of data per line.

Comment: is the comparing itself to itself throwing it off?

Comment: Yep, when I look at my output, it fires the overlap message when the view lines up with itself in both loops.

Answer (score 1):

You figured out what the problem was. Here's how to add the check that the two views are not the same:

```
for (UIView *view1 in self.myArrayOfViews) {
    for (UIView *view2 in self.myArrayOfViews) {    
        if (view1 != view2 && CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)) {
            NSLog(@"overlap!");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but one more thing. if I stick an else statement and run another NSLog for that, both if and else occur when there's an overlap with one view in particular. It happened with all of the views until I stuck and else if (view1 != view2) in there.

Comment: It's not possible for the code in both the `if` and `else` blocks to run, given the same pair of views, so I'm not sure what you're saying exactly. It would help if you told us what the `frame` values were. Also, are the views all siblings (do they all have the same `superview`)?